# How to parse a kafka topic which contains data in the form of nested json?

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am trying to read a kafka topic and stream it to my sink. To read the data, I wrote the following code.

topic data in json:

```
{
"HiveData": {
"Tablename": "HiveTablename1",
"Rowcount": "3213423",
"lastupdateddate": "2021-02-24 13:04:14"
},
"HbaseData": [
{
"Tablename": "HbaseTablename1",
"Rowcount": "23543",
"lastupdateddate": "2021-02-23 12:03:11"
}
],
"PostgresData": [
{
"Tablename": "PostgresTablename1",
"Rowcount": "23454345",
"lastupdateddate": "2021-02-23 12:03:11"
}
]
}
```

Below is the code I wrote for parsing the topic:

```
 def streamData(): DataFrame = {
    val kafkaDF = spark.readStream.format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "server:port")
      .option("subscribe", "topic_name")
      .load()
    kafkaDF.select(from_json(col("HiveData"), topic_schema).as("HiveData")).selectExpr("HiveData.tablename as table", "HiveData.Rowcount as rowcount", "HiveData.lastupdateddate as lastupdateddate") 
    kafkaDF
 }
```

But this code works if the json is in the format of:

```
{"Tablename": "HiveTablename1","Rowcount": "3213423","lastupdateddate": "2021-02-24 13:04:14"}
```

I want to parse the json and get HiveData into a seperate dataframe and a seperate dataframe for HBaseData and the same for PostgresData. The code I wrote is working if the json data is in a single line.
Could anyone let me know how to parse the data into multiple dataframes if it is in nested format as mentioned in the beginning of this question ?
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

option("multiline", "true")